# They didn't object to his (being given a second chance)

Tags: possessives, ellipses

> a. They objected to my being given a second chance, but not to his being given a second chance.

Can you omit the second verb phrase *being given a second chance* as in (b)?

> b. They objected to my being given a second chance, but not to his.

If so, is this a case of ellipsis?

If not, why not?

Comment: Using the ACC-ing structure is highly formal and stylised, and I'd say the parallelling becomes too awkward. I'd restructure here. 'They objected when the employee was given a second chance, but were less critical when the intern was treated similarly.'

Comment: BTW, how many interns are there?  And why is possessive being used at all?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How about using 'my' and 'his'?

Comment: @HotLicks I wanted to know if the possessive is merely being used as a determiner, in which case the ellipsis should work, or if it's being used as something else.

Comment: Even "They objected to my being given a second chance, but not to his being given a second chance" sounds off ... petty at the best, ridiculously stuffy at worst.  "They objected to my being given a second chance, but not to his" would have Orwell turning in his grave.

Answer (score -1):

I would. But, I would also remove the comma after "chance", since there aren't two independent clauses.

It's [verbal phrase ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase_ellipsis).

Comment: I don't think _being given a second chance_ is a noun or noun phrase. It's a verb phrase headed by _being_. So I don't understand how it could be a case of noun ellipsis. If you know any example of this kind of ellipsis, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think the comma is wrong. If you search "but not to the" in Google News, you'll see many start with a comma: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_koKR818KR818&biw=1280&bih=610&tbm=nws&sxsrf=ALeKk018YRfSXSpsU31Q33P-mj-p3rUJUw%3A1585189595420&ei=2xJ8XsabGcOsmAWknoPoBw&q=%22but+not+to+the%22&oq=%22but+not+to+the%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0.0.49731.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.AuBPwYjIL4o

Comment: Confused gerund with verbal noun. But it's this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase_ellipsis. It seems you already knew the answer.